# VkApi GetConverstions Access denied

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, api

Столкнулся с проблемой: Пытаюсь получить список диалогов пользователя после авторизации. Выдает ошибку №15 Access denied. Вот строка для получения токена:

```
    Browser.Navigate("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id="
                          + VkAPI.__APPID
                          + "&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=friends&messages&photos&response_type=token&v=5.103");
```

Для самой авторизации пользователя использую конструктор:

```
public VkAPI(string token)
    {
        api = new VkApi();

        ApiAuthParams authParams = new ApiAuthParams()
        {
            AccessToken = token,
            Settings = Settings.All
        };

        api.Authorize(authParams);
    }
```

Метод в котором возникает ошибка:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetDialogList()
    {
        List<string> userNames = new List<string>();
        GetConversationsParams conversationsParams = new GetConversationsParams
        {
            Count = 20,
            Extended = true
        };
        var conversations = api.Messages
            .GetConversations(conversationsParams).Items; //Access denied

        foreach(var dialog in conversations)
        {
            userNames.Add(dialog.Conversation.ChatSettings.Title);
        }

        return userNames;
    }
```

Казалось бы, необходимые права имеются, сам токен я тоже получаю, все по документации от самих разработчиков, но в чем тогда проблема?

Comment: Спрашиваете про один метод, а показываете другой

Comment: @aepot добавил сам метод с ошибкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с Messages с токеном пользователя нужно пройти модерацию администрацией Vk и получить доступ, как я понял. Подробнее тут: https://vk.com/dev/messages_api